# Wkhtmltopdf and Google Charts

Tags: php, google-visualization, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf (0.12.4 with patched qt) and phpwkhtmltopdf to create PDF files from html. In some of these PDFs, I need to include several charts and to do this I've been using google charts. The problem I'm facing currently arises when trying to create a pdf that has several pages containing charts. The process errors out with the following message:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[>                                                           ] 0%
[>                                                           ] 1%
[=>                                                          ] 2%
[=>                                                          ] 3%
[==>                                                         ] 4%
[===>                                                        ] 5%
[===>                                                        ] 6%
[====>                                                       ] 7%
[====>                                                       ] 8%
[=====>                                                      ] 9%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[=======>                                                    ] 13%
[==========>                                                 ] 18%
[============>                                               ] 21%
[===============>                                            ] 26%
[===============>                                            ] 26%
[==================>                                         ] 30%
[=====================>                                      ] 35%
[======================>                                     ] 38%
[=========================>                                  ] 43%
[===========================>                                ] 46%
[==============================>                             ] 51%
[=================================>                          ] 55%
[===================================>                        ] 59%
[=====================================>                      ] 63%
[========================================>                   ] 67%
[==========================================>                 ] 71%
[=============================================>              ] 76%
[=============================================>              ] 76%
[==============================================>             ] 78%
[==============================================>             ] 78%
[===============================================>            ] 79%
[================================================>           ] 80%
[================================================>           ] 81%
[====================================================>       ] 87%
[=====================================================>      ] 89%
[======================================================>     ] 90%
[======================================================>     ] 91%
[=======================================================>    ] 92%
[=========================================================>  ] 95%
[============================================================] 100%
```

Not a very helpful error as you can see.

I'm using a 1 second js delay in order to give the charts a chance to load. If I remove this delay, the PDF is created without error, but none of the charts are displayed. Also, if I keep the delay at 1 second but reduce the number of pages that contain a chart, everything works perfectly.
I'm able to create a 10 page PDF with 5 "chart pages", but if I try for 11 pages with 6 charts, it fails. I need to be able to handle more like 10 or 15 charts in a single PDF.

Any insight into this error or suggestions for an alternative approach are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @WhiteHat, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that with no luck. Got the same results as before.

Answer (score 1):

Using '--window-status ready' combined with the following JS solved the loading issue.  The problem is a timing issue, which is solved by the JS function:

```
function loadGoogleGraph(graphCallback) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('not-ready-yet');
            if (
                google.visualization !== undefined
                && google.visualization.DataTable !== undefined
                && google.visualization.PieChart !== undefined
            ){
                clearInterval(interval);
                console.log('ready');
                window.status = 'ready';
                graphCallback()
              }
        }, 100);
    }


    loadGoogleGraph(<YOUR FUNCTION>)
```

instead of

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(<YOUR FUNCTION>);
```

Above is an adaptation from Abisco: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/255#issuecomment-628815194

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem on pages with heavy loads that include charts.  It's tricky to get the timing right, and I've found after many hours of pulling my hair out that the key (for me at least) is to make sure both 'sides' of the equation are timed correctly with the longer time being on the wkhtmltopdf wait state.

IE on the google charts side, I include a delay sufficient to prevent the stupid Chrome 'slow page load' error by adding a JS delay on the actual library pull:

```
setTimeout(function(){google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'callback':'drawChart', 'packages':['corechart', 'bar']})}, 1200);
```

1200 works fine for my needs, you might need to bump it higher depending on what you are pulling from google.

The important one (for me) was to make sure wkhtmltopdf was balancing the delay and adding a bit more delay for itself (google delay + processing delay).  For this page I added a 2200 ms delay on the pdf side:

```
--javascript-delay: 2200
```

Just wouldn't work at all until I got the two items to talk in balance.  As you said, the charts won't display at all without the delay - this shows a good likelihood that you've got half the error resolved.  It may help to try adding the delay to the other side and see if it helps.